# Unable to add single backslash within a string value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider if I want the output for value as '1\2':

```
>>value='1'+'\\'+'2'
>>print(value)
1\2
```

This works as expected. However, if I add this value into a dictionary, I get double backslashes. Is there a way I can keep the string without getting modified into double backslashes?

```
>>print({'key': value})
{'key': '1\\2'}
```

Answer (score 5):

when you print a dictionary it will print the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the values

```
strg = "\\"

print(str(strg))  # \
print(repr(strg)) # '\\'
```

so everything is fine. i would not know of a way around that right now except you write your own string class and override [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (which feels like overkill)...

---

so you really want to achieve that. overkill is then! :)

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


strg = MyStr("\\")

print(str(strg))  # \
print(repr(strg)) # \
```

this may break things (especially if `eval` is involved).

or:

```
from collections import UserString

class MyStr(UserString):
    def __index__(self, strg):
        super().__init__(strg)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data
```

Comment: Yes right! I was aware that repr values were getting printed in case of dict. So question was directed along the lines of what would be the best way to just print '\' within a dictionary.

Comment: @WehWell ok, added a work-around (two versions actually).